# Python decorator that is a method in a class which is in different module

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I want to use a decorator which is a function in a class that is in different python module.

Creating an instance of the class globally and using the decorator like '@global_obj.my_decor' would work.

But I somehow feel it doesn't look clean. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Decorate the function in that class with a [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to avoid a global object (I probably would want to), you can always just avoid the syntactic sugar and create and object and decorate your function by hand:

```
In [23]: class Foo:
    ...:     def deco(self, f):
    ...:         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:             print("hi")
    ...:             result = f(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:             print("I am decorated")
    ...:             return result
    ...:         return wrapper
    ...:

In [24]: def func(x, y):
    ...:     return 2*x + 3*y
    ...:
    ...:

In [25]: func = Foo().deco(func)

In [26]: func(3,2)
hi
I am decorated
Out[26]: 12
```

To me, this suggests that you might be better off without the class to begin with. But without more details, I can only guess.

Comment: missing the `@staticmethod`

Comment: @aydow it doesn't require it. If it *was* a static-method, then you could use the `@Foo.static_deco` syntactic sugar. I'm assuming the OP actually requires a class with state. But if you are going to use a `@staticmethod`, why not just a plain decorator function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks. I just avoided using decorator.

I am using Falcon APIs in python which supports middleware. I have put the logic(actually auth-token validation) inside middleware, so its called every time before my actual APIs are called. And its coded only at one place